# Setting value stored at address using x86 ASM

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I am trying to get my head around some inline ASM but for some reason this isn't behaving as I would have expected. Why isn't this setting the value of x equal to 62?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 525;
    int* y = &x;

    _asm
    {
        mov eax, 62
        mov [y], eax
    }

    printf("%i", x);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The code results in 525 being output. I expected it to be 62.

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said.. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a perfectly excusable misunderstanding here:

> surely [y] would mean [0xCCCCCCCC] (assuming the address of x was 0xCCCCCCCC)

In high-level theory, yes. The trouble is, in actual assembly `[0xCCCCCCCC]` makes no sense - the CPU can't dereference a memory address directly - it can only *load* a value from that address into a register, then dereference *that*.

Similarly, since `y` is a *variable*, not a *register*, it's implicitly treated as an address<sup>1</sup> i.e. `y` inside the `asm` block is the equivalent of `&y` in the C code outside<sup>2</sup>. As you can see by stepping through in a debugger, what happened is the assembler simply ignored the brackets that don't make sense (rather than throwing a helpful error) and assembled the equivalent of `mov y, eax`.

The way to get what you expect would be something like this:

```
asm {
    mov eax, 62
    mov edx, y
    mov [edx], eax
}
```

[1] this clearly isn't GCC. GCC extended asm is a *whole* different ball game...

[2] somewhat of a simplification - it's an "address" from a C point of view, but in assembly context it's a memory operand, which is really more like the *use* of an address. When I compiled this, `y` came out as `[ebp-20]`, which from the high level view is "an address on the stack".

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a bit and the code works perfectly. However, according to your explanation shouldn't the second instruction, `mov edx, y`, result in the _address_ of `y` being copied to edx and not the _value_? Obviously I can see it is indeed copying `y` by value but if you say inside the `_asm` block it is actually the equivalent of `&y` in C, why is it not copying the address of `y`? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @user1727141 I say "equivalent" because there's not really a 1:1 correspondence - the way an "address" is used depends on the instruction - `mov` only cares about moving data so uses a memory operand as a pointer to dereference. To put the address itself in a register there's the "load effective address" instruction: `lea edx, y` would would do exactly what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You are loadig the *address* of `x` into `y`. Then you are storing `62` in the *address* (again!) of the *variable* `y` -- that's what the `[..]` syntax means. So you are not modifying the variable `x` but rather the value stored at *(*y). (And it's a small wonder that does not crash your program.)

You probably want

```
mov [&y], eax
```

(if your compiler accepts that syntax).

Comment: I already tried that before I asked the question, it doesn't work. error C2400: inline assembler syntax error in 'first operand'; found 'AND'

Comment: Also, surely [y] would mean [0xCCCCCCCC] (assuming the address of x was 0xCCCCCCCC). Therefore [0xCCCCCCCC] == x.. Right?